# How to extract words from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, extract, text-extraction

I have a string in the form of:

```
 sent = "Software Development = 1831".
```

I want to extract only words from the string i.e. "Software Development".

How I can extract this in Python.

Comment: What did you already try ?

Comment: `sent.split('=')[0].strip()` + SEARCH !

Answer (score 4):

You can try `split` :

```
>>> sent="Software Development = 1831"
>>> sent.split("=")[0]
'Software Development '
```

Comment: Thank you it's working now :)

Comment: And to get whatever is on the other side you would use sent.split("=")[1]

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> str="Software Development = 1831"

>>> str.split()
['Software', 'Development', '=', '1831']

or 

>>> str.split("=")
['Software Development ', ' 1831']
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have spaces between `'='`, hence your code should look like this

```
sent="Software Development = 1831"
answer=sent.split(" = ")[0] # space before and after =
```